# Action in the concurrent thread is not executed when main thread is waiting

Tags: java, eclipse, events, swing, concurrency

I have an application which use temporary tables (existed in the scope of user session) and complex data processing.

For debug purposes I need to execute queries to this temporary tables during the application processing.

I added some additional logic as aspects (AspectJ) and run my application as load-time weaving application in Eclipse (using AJDT/ JDT weaving plugin).

I do the following: after getting new connection I create another thread with gui and pass the connection to it (would be described later).

After each query the main application thread waiting for the message from gui thread to continue the work (that gives me an opportunity to make queries and see intermediate results in temporary tables). Messaging is implemented using BlockingQueue.

In the GUI I have a frame with text area for query and two buttons "Run query" and "Release main thread".

I wanted that pressing the "Run query" button will execute the query and show the results on the frame. And pressing the button "Release main thread" will send the message to the main thread to continue the work.

The problem is when the main thread is waiting for blockingQueue.take(), pressing the button "Run query" causes the frame to freeze and do nothing (it looks like gui becomes unresponsive).

When the main thread is waiting for blockingQueue.take(), "Release main thread" forks fine (but not after "Run query" pressing).

When the main thread is running (I put plenty of objects in the queue), "Run query" button works normally and I can see query results.

At first I've tried manipulations with EDT and events dispatching, but nothing has helped me. Have you any ideas of the problem?

```
//aspect on 'newConnection' pointcut 
after() returning (final Connection connection): newConnection()  {
    gUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GuiView(blockingQueue, connection);
            }
        };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(gUI);
}

    //GuiView code extract for button with query data retrieval action

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {               
      ResultSet rs = ConnectionManipulator.executeStatement(
          queryTextAreaG.getText()
      );
    ///....result parsing logic

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception!");
    } finally {

    }
    //....result out logic


    }
});
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you showed some code of what you are doing; your textual description doesn't give enough hints to people who could help.

Answer (score 0):

GUIs usually run in the main thread (not only on Java), so if you let your main thread block, you block your GUI as well and it freezes.

**EDIT**

I think you got SwingUtilities.invokeLater wrong: it is being used to execute part of the code in the main event loop thread, so usually is being called from the background thread, not the other way round. Now it looks like the query were being executed in the event loop thread thus blocking GUI.

Let the query be executed in a normal thread and when it is ready call the mainthread callback using SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

Comment: No, the button with the simple action ("Release main thread") is working fine, even when the main thread blocks.

Comment: A puzzle, without seeing more code I can't say what's wrong. But in anyway you shouldn't block the main thread. Let the query inform the main thread using callback into the main thread. Well now I have an idea, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Sorry for trouble. Description is above

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for trouble. The problem was in the incorrect pointcut description (not attached to the code above).
I had this the pointcut around:

```
PreparedStatement around(): prepareStatement() {
        if (gUI != null) {
            try {
                blockingQueue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally {

            }
        }
return proceed();
```

But **ConnectionManipulator.executeStatement** uses prepareStatement() also .
So it executes blockingQueue.take(), which causes the GUI event thread to stop.
I`ve corrected the pointcut desription and the problem gone away.
Thank you all.